# Confused by my vpn not working

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vpn

I am trying to use a VPN. It requires me to use F5 VPN software which pops up a windows saying "connected" with information about bytes sent and received.

[image]

If I run `ifconfig` I see:

```
enp9s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.178.53  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.178.255
        inet6 fe80::88b4:8386:46b2:b870  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 18:c0:4d:20:ba:e3  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 2614623  bytes 1488386639 (1.4 GB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 203768  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 1591444  bytes 424169212 (424.1 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
[...]

tun0: flags=81<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING>  mtu 1384
        inet 172.21.181.120  netmask 255.255.255.255  destination 1.1.1.1
        inet6 2001:630:e4:4280::1582  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 fe80::e3a6:ca39:2dd9:c23e  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        unspec 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  txqueuelen 500  (UNSPEC)
        RX packets 1544  bytes 416098 (416.0 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 1690  bytes 126644 (126.6 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

If I run `ip route list` I get this:

```
default via 192.168.178.1 dev enp9s0 proto dhcp metric 100 
1.1.1.1 dev tun0 proto kernel scope link src 172.21.181.120 
4.234.210.7 via 172.21.181.120 dev tun0 metric 1 
10.0.0.0/8 via 172.21.181.120 dev tun0 metric 1 
10.42.0.0/24 dev wlp1s0 proto kernel scope link src 10.42.0.1 metric 600 
20.49.140.221 via 172.21.181.120 dev tun0 metric 1 
20.49.230.123 via 172.21.181.120 dev tun0 metric 1 
34.242.90.168 via 172.21.181.120 dev tun0 metric 1 
34.243.28.11 via 172.21.181.120 dev tun0 metric 1 
34.248.57.236 via 172.21.181.120 dev tun0 metric 1 
51.140.73.190 via 172.21.181.120 dev tun0 metric 1 
51.140.80.148 via 172.21.181.120 dev tun0 metric 1 
51.143.224.92 via 172.21.181.120 dev tun0 metric 1 
51.179.223.115 via 172.21.181.120 dev tun0 metric 1 
52.50.187.38 via 172.21.181.120 dev tun0 metric 1 
54.72.152.131 via 172.21.181.120 dev tun0 metric 1 
54.72.239.170 via 172.21.181.120 dev tun0 metric 1 
54.73.203.23 via 172.21.181.120 dev tun0 metric 1 
54.229.195.216 via 172.21.181.120 dev tun0 metric 1 
78.25.196.229 via 172.21.181.120 dev tun0 metric 1 
104.16.117.12 via 172.21.181.120 dev tun0 metric 1 
104.16.118.12 via 172.21.181.120 dev tun0 metric 1 
104.16.119.12 via 172.21.181.120 dev tun0 metric 1 
104.16.120.12 via 172.21.181.120 dev tun0 metric 1 
104.16.121.12 via 172.21.181.120 dev tun0 metric 1 
104.18.0.20 via 172.21.181.120 dev tun0 metric 1 
104.18.1.20 via 172.21.181.120 dev tun0 metric 1 
116.203.77.235 via 172.21.181.120 dev tun0 metric 1 
130.14.29.110 via 172.21.181.120 dev tun0 metric 1 
130.246.130.28 via 172.21.181.120 dev tun0 metric 1 
130.246.130.29 via 172.21.181.120 dev tun0 metric 1 
130.246.130.121 via 172.21.181.120 dev tun0 metric 1 
130.246.130.164 via 172.21.181.120 dev tun0 metric 1 
130.246.130.165 via 172.21.181.120 dev tun0 metric 1 
130.246.130.166 via 172.21.181.120 dev tun0 metric 1 
130.246.130.167 via 172.21.181.120 dev tun0 metric 1 
130.246.130.171 via 172.21.181.120 dev tun0 metric 1 
130.246.130.172 via 172.21.181.120 dev tun0 metric 1 
130.246.130.173 via 172.21.181.120 dev tun0 metric 1 
137.222.0.0/16 via 172.21.181.120 dev tun0 metric 1 
137.222.251.108 via 192.168.178.1 dev enp9s0 metric 1 
151.101.16.95 via 172.21.181.120 dev tun0 metric 1 
151.101.16.152 via 172.21.181.120 dev tun0 metric 1 
160.109.109.97 via 172.21.181.120 dev tun0 metric 1 
162.159.129.81 via 172.21.181.120 dev tun0 metric 1 
162.159.129.87 via 172.21.181.120 dev tun0 metric 1 
162.159.130.81 via 172.21.181.120 dev tun0 metric 1 
162.159.130.87 via 172.21.181.120 dev tun0 metric 1 
169.254.0.0/16 dev enp9s0 scope link metric 1000 
172.16.0.0/12 via 172.21.181.120 dev tun0 metric 1 
173.254.190.144 via 172.21.181.120 dev tun0 metric 1 
185.249.69.250 via 172.21.181.120 dev tun0 metric 1 
192.168.0.0/16 via 172.21.181.120 dev tun0 metric 1 
192.168.178.0/24 dev enp9s0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.178.53 metric 100 
192.168.178.1 via 192.168.178.53 dev enp9s0 proto unspec metric 1 
194.34.213.28 via 172.21.181.120 dev tun0 metric 1
```

But when I google "what is my ip" I still see my normal IP address  as if the VPN isn't running.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The VPN interface being up and working alone does not make your traffic go through that interface. The routing configuration has to be adjusted. What is the output of `ip route list`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The VPN is being used in "split tunnel" mode, so that only traffic intended for the VPN destination is being sent across the VPN, and everything else is sent using your normal routing

You can find out the particular route being used for any specific IP address:

```
ip route get 8.8.8.8          # Your usual route
ip route get 20.49.230.123    # VPN
```

On my system here the first of these reports something like this,

```
8.8.8.8 via 192.168.1.1 dev enxb827eb315364 src 192.168.1.18
^target     ^gateway    ^interface              ^my IP address
```

Comment: Ah. Is there any way to change that?

Comment: @Simd it depends almost entirely on who manages the VPN tunnel. Is it for work, or a subscription service that you have bought yourself?

Comment: Work.i may give up

Comment: @Simd ask them. You can also do what OpenVPN does and add two halves to route through the VPN. `ip route add REMOTE_VPN_ENDPOINT via 192.168.178.1` and then `ip route add 0.0.0.0/1 via 172.21.181.120` and `ip route add 128.0.0.0/1 via 172.21.181.120`. It might work. It might not. You might find that your DNS servers need to be routed via your local gateway so test initially with _numerical `ping`_ (`ping 1.1.1.1`) rather than _`ping` by name_ (`ping one.one.one.one`)